# nginx or apache for comet based PHP application?

Tags: php, apache, webserver, nginx

I am building a PHP comet based application. Which web server should I use in the backend? Apache / nginx (this is what most forums say) or something else would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using PHP at all for this purpose. PHP is synchronous, therefore every open comet connection will block a PHP process (or Apache process if mod_php). Here an asynchronous language shall be used, JavaScript for example. (See [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org). If you are using comet for a chat, have a look at [node_chat](http://github.com/ry/node_chat))

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a comet app too, i guess apache + php (a classic) and APE with comet server beside may be a great solution

ape-project.org/